# easiest way to create bootable windows 10 usb from debian

Tags: debian, usb, windows, iso

The title describes it all...

I have previously tried with Balena Etcher but it didn't work as expected.

Also, i can't get WoeUSB installed on my Debian because i have some pathetic problems with Snap.
Is there another way that is not extremely complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t make a bootable usb anymore. You need to buy a cd now and install through the cd because it might ask you the product code and if you find this code only on a real windows product not a fake that you install from  the internet.

Comment: let's say that it's not the image from the microsoft site.

Comment: When I visit https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO with linux, i can easily select/download the normal 5.1GiB iso ...

Comment: I already have an image of WIndows 10. That's not a problem. And it won't ask for the CD Key ( I can skip that part)

Comment: You need a product key that is only on the catalog of the cd that you will buy. I recommend you to go to a computer store and ask him to install windows 10. He will do it for 5$

Comment: @JohnBaltariu then what is your problem ?

Comment: my problem is that i don't know how to make it bootable on an USB!!!
read the question carefully.

Comment: Why don’t you borrow 2 min the laptop of a friend to make it ?!?!

Comment: that's indeed a solution... but I'd also like to know how to make bootable images because i plan to switch to Linux full time.

Comment: type in the terminal sudo dd if=/home/..../name.iso of=/dev/sdb

Comment: /home/.../name.iso is the path to your iso file and /dev/sdb is the path to your usb then if i am not wrong you are good to go

Comment: !!! It can be once sdb or sdc you need to see how it’s named

Comment: does the "dd" command make the image bootable also?

Comment: Give it a try, i haven’t done it myself

Comment: @JohnBaltariu  did it worked ?

Comment: i got it to finally work by cloning and building "WoeUSB"